# Generalizing circles passing through two points

Tags: circles, conic-sections

You can easily construct a circle which has $A=(0, 0)$ as its center and two points $B$, $C$ of the same distance to $A=(0, 0)$ being located on it:

[image: circle with points]

I wonder if it is possible to have an ellipse which also has $A=(0, 0)$ as its center, but intersecting two points $B$, $C$ which have not the same distance from $(0, 0)$. The foci of the ellipse should be parallel to the two points which should intersect the ellipse. Sketching the solution, it should look somewhat as follows:

[image]

How would you create an ellipse equation in terms of $B$ and $C$?

Comment: Do you mean $BC$ must be parallel to the line of the foci? That's impossible, unless $AB=AC$.

Comment: Any conic is determined by 5 pts. You've provided 2: $B$ and $C$; taking the origin as the center gives 2 more: the reflections of $B$ and $C$ in the origin. You also want the major axis to be parallel to line $BC$; knowing the conic's center, we can draw that line of that axis; as it's axis of *symmetry*, we can take the reflections of $B$ and $C$ in *that* to get two more pts on the conic. So, we actually have *6* pts to work with. However, it's easy to see that a line parallel to $BC$ runs through all four of those reflected pts. The conic is not an ellipse, but a degenerate parabola.